# Im rusty, can't figure out how to do exception handling right in Java swing

Tags: java, swing, exception

So, i have this program, and it works okey. But i have a problem. You aren't suppose to be able to add an ID that's already in the ID table in my array.

This is the code for my listener on my add button (laggTill)
I don't know how to make the exception stop the data from being added. So when i for example put letters in my ID box im not suppose to be able to add it. But it still does. By JOptionPane comes upp and says the error message but still add it to the array. How do i stop this from happening?
I though an exception stopped everything, but apparently it doesn't.

And i also need the exception for ID checking to work.. i don't know how to do it.. i haven't been doing this for a while so i can't figure it out.

So, Basicly, My questions are: how do you make an exception hinder the data from being added. And how do i make my class check if the ID is unique?

Main class:

private class Listener implements ActionListener {

```
    String getId;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        if (ae.getSource() == laggTill) {

            DTODjur dto = new DTODjur();

            dto.djurNamn = textFieldNamn.getText();
            dto.djurKategori = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            try {
                dto.djurID = Integer.parseInt(textFieldId.getText());
                dao.laggTill(dto);
            } catch (WrongDjurID ex) {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            }
            textArea.setText("Lade till: \nID: " + textFieldId.getText() + "\nNamn: " + textFieldNamn.getText() + "\nKategori: "+ comboBox.getSelectedItem());
        }
```

DAO class:

```
public void laggTill(DTODjur dto) throws WrongDjurID {

    boolean found = false;

    openDB();

    try {
        int djurid = dto.djurID;
        String djurnamn = dto.djurNamn;
        String djurkategori = dto.djurKategori;

        String SQL = "INSERT INTO h12mjont_djur(djurID,djurNamn,djurKategori) VALUES('" + djurid + "','" + djurnamn + "','" + djurkategori + "')";

        System.out.println(SQL);
        st.executeUpdate(SQL);
        found=true;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
    if (!found) {
        throw new WrongDjurID("Id ska inte innehålla bokstäver");
    }else  {

    dtodjur = getAll();
   }

    closeDB();
    dtodjur = getAll();
}
```

Comment: Well, what SQL exception are you getting?

Comment: You could do a `Select` or `Count` query to check if the id does exist before trying to do the `Insert` query.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you are catching exceptions then proceeding as if nothing had happened by writing code after the catches.  I'd suggest moving all catch logic to the very end of each method.  In your first block change it to this:

String getId;

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    if (ae.getSource() == laggTill) {

        DTODjur dto = new DTODjur();

        dto.djurNamn = textFieldNamn.getText();
        dto.djurKategori = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
        try {
            dto.djurID = Integer.parseInt(textFieldId.getText());
            dao.laggTill(dto);
            textArea.setText("Lade till: \nID: " + textFieldId.getText() + "\nNamn: " + textFieldNamn.getText() + "\nKategori: "+ comboBox.getSelectedItem());
        } catch (WrongDjurID ex) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

2nd block of code:

```
public void laggTill(DTODjur dto) throws WrongDjurID {
   openDB();

   try {
    int djurid = dto.djurID;
    String djurnamn = dto.djurNamn;
    String djurkategori = dto.djurKategori;

    String SQL = "INSERT INTO h12mjont_djur(djurID,djurNamn,djurKategori) VALUES('" + djurid + "','" + djurnamn + "','" + djurkategori + "')";

    System.out.println(SQL);
    st.executeUpdate(SQL);
    dtodjur = getAll();

   } catch (SQLException ex) {
      throw new WrongDjurID("Id ska inte innehålla bokstäver");
   } finally {
      closeDB();
   }
}
```

Now the getAll() call will not be run if an exception is thrown.  Previously you were running getAll() even if an exception was thrown which would re-read the list.  Remember to use finally clause to clean up after you read the DB regardless of if it was successful or an exception was thrown.

Comment: Well, thank you! It was quite obvious when i saw it... but as i said, i haven't been doing this for a while. Thanks for the help!